# Open a specific email in Mutt in just one command

Tags: email, mutt

Reading a specific email in Mutt is simple.

Just do

```
$ mutt
```

in the terminal. It opens and then directly from there you type the message ID from the message you want to read, followed by enter. Simple.

But I was still wondering if this could be done even more easily by doing everything in one command using certain parameters.

Like:

```
$ mutt -[parameter] [message ID]
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 3):

You can call any function from the command line with the `-e` parameter. For example,

```
mutt -e "push 100\n\n"
```

will jump to, and show, the 100th message. The `push` command is emulates to keyboard input.

You can use a shell variable for the message number:

```
MEESAGE_INDEX=100
mutt -e "push ${MESSAGE_INDEX}\n\n"
```

Note that "message ID" is a unique field inside each email header, and not what you are referring to, which is the message index in the folder.